# Checking for unfilled fields with PHP

Tags: php, forms, field

I am creating a checkout page that requires the client to fill out his personal information as well as his credit card details (this part using stripe).

I was wondering, what is the best way to check whether the fields are filled up or not? Shall I do it in the processingPayment.php that $_POSTs the fields and processes payment, and in case the fields were not filled, I would redirect back to checkout?

Or is it a better idea to use js to check on the spot before submitting the form?

if in the processing page, I would try something like this:

```
if (empty($firsName) || empty($lastName) || empty($address) || empty ($city) || empty ($state) || empty($zip))
{
header('Location: checkout.php');
}
```

But I would need to re-send the values that were entered so the checkout page receives them and the user doesn't have to re-fill every field again...

Comment: Were it me, I'd do the validation _before_ the form is submitted, with Javascript. That way, any request sent to your PHP file will satisfy the few base requirements so you wouldn't need to send them back. If this is an option, [questions like this one might be relevant to you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339230/javascript-form-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
    if( empty($val) ) {
        echo "$key is empty";
    }
}
```

The **best** method with PHP is to have an array of possible arguments:

```
$array = array('firstName', 'lastName');

foreach($array as $val) {
    if( empty($_POST[$val]) ) {
        echo "$val is empty";
    }
}
```

Otherwise, client side validation works too, but can always be disabled. To be completely safe, use both client and server side.

Comment: **samyb8** was asking about _flashing data_ too. just pointing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session to store the entered data, but you would need to check each value separately:

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen(trim($value)) <= 0) {    //You could replace '0'
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
}

?>
```

**FORM**

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" value="<?php $_SESSION['firstName'] ? $_SESSION['firstName'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="First Name" />
....
</form>
```

The `$_SESSION['firstName'] ? $_SESSION['firstName'] : '';` is the same as

```
if ($_SESSION['firstName']) return $_SESSION['firstName']
else return '';
```

it is more readable in the HTML(View) that the full if statement

Answer (score 0):

```
$var  = isset($_POST['field'])  ? $_POST['field']  : '';
$var2 = isset($_POST['field2']) ? $_POST['field2'] : '';
// and so on

if( empty($var) || empty($var2) )
{
   //it's empty
}
```

Comment: Instead of just code, could you explain how this answers the asker's question? It would make the answer much more useful to people who find this answer.